# Nginx as reverse proxy: how do I instruct nginx to cache one particular page for duration?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

How do I instruct nginx to cache a particular page for a fixed duration?

Say I have a home page at `quintin.com/index.php`. Now I want nginx to cache this for 5 mins and then hit apache to take the new one. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup a cache zone and configure a specific location to be cached with the [nginx proxy/cache module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache). There's a [blog post](http://andytson.com/blog/2010/04/page-level-caching-with-nginx/) about a simple setup.
Basically you need to create a place associated with a *zone*:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx keys_zone=anonymous:10m;
```

and then assign stuff to be cached on that zone:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080/;
    proxy_cache   anonymous;
}
```